# Are there zero-dimensional topological spaces and are they not discrete?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a topological space. Are there zero-dimensional subsets of $\mathcal{T}$ and are they not discrete?

My question is about Noetherian spaces, but I would like to know in the general case too.

Comment: The Cantor set is zero-dimensional.

Comment: Both $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q$ are zero-dimensional sub-spaces of $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general topology zero-dimensional spaces are quite common:

Discrete spaces are zero-dimensional and products of zero-dimensional spaces are again zero-dimensional, so spaces like $\{0,1\}^\omega$ (which is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, $\{0,1\}$ is discrete) and $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ (homeomorphic to the irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{N}$ has the discrete topology, like it has as a real subspace) are zero-dimensional subspaces, as well as all subspaces of zero-dimensional spaces. $\mathbb{Q}$ is also a non-discrete zero-dimensional space, as are $\omega+1 \simeq \{0\} \cup\{\frac1n: n \in \mathbb{N}^+\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, as well as all ordinals in the order topology. The [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) is also a famous example.
A whole class of spaces is given by the [Stone spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_space) of Boolean algebras: every Boolean algebra $A$ has an associated zero-dimensional space $X$, such that $A$ is isomorphic to the set of clopen sets of $X$. So in general topology, zero-dimensional spaces are widely studied and form a large class.

In fact, one can show that $X$ is zero-dimensional and Hausdorff iff there is some set $I$ such that $X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of the so-called Cantor cube $\{0,1\}^I$.

I cannot offhand think of any examples of zero-dimensional *Noetherian* spaces, besides the finite discrete spaces. There might not be any other examples than that? At least $T_1$ ones: if we don't care about separation axioms we can take an indiscrete space or more generally any space such that the topology is a finite partition of the underlying set. (finite to get Noetherian, partition to get zero-dimensional, as all opens are then closed too.)

Comment: This is a great explanation! My objective is to show that an irreducible closed subset of a Noetherian space is a single point. For this I wanted to show that any closed subset of a Noetherian space is discrete, since I have already shown that it can be decomposed as a finite union of irreducible closed. But I don't know if this is the best way.

Comment: A space with the *indiscrete* topology is zero-dimensional and Noetherian, isn't it?

Comment: @bof sure, it's a very boring example though.

Comment: Sorry, when I said " My objective is to show that an (proper) irreducible closed subset of a Noetherian space is a single point", the Noetherian space has dimension $1$. The original question give a $k$-variety $V$ one-dimensional and, I proved in a previous question that every $k$-variety is a Noetherian space.

Comment: All 0-dimensional noetherian spaces are indeed finite disjoint unions of indiscrete spaces. A Noetherian space X contains finitely many irreducible components. These have to be disjoint. Otherwise they have a point in common whose closure is again irreducible contradicting dim=0. Let x be a point in X. Then its closure has to agree with an irreducible component. Hence the irreducible components are indiscrete.

For details see:
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/004U
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0050